# What is the relationship between the pressure of water and volume collected by a shower?

Tags: pressure, flow

Consider a showerhead that releases water at a constant flow rate and temperature. What is the relationship between the pressure of water coming out of the shower and the volume of water collected in a bucket after $t$ seconds? Is Bernoulli's equation relevant here? Or should I just experimentally test it? I’m wondering if there is any theoretical work on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the water pressure in the pipes, then the flow rate is likely proportional to the square root of that pressure, and the volume fill time is inversely proportional to that. I.e.

$$\mathrm {time} \propto \frac{1}{\dot V} \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{P}}
$$

I say "likely" because the assumption is flow through an orifice based on Bernoulli's principle:

$$\Delta P = \frac 1 2 \rho u^2
$$

Which experience says would model your scenario well.

The proportionality factor depends on the exact flow resistance of the shower head restriction, which you would need to find empirically.

(I noticed you mentioned "constant flow rate." If you are truly assuming that, then your fill time of any fixed volume is of course fixed.  Furthermore when you say "pressure" of the stream I think you mean velocity.  The pressure is always 1 atmosphere.)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, time is fixed. By pressure, I mean something like $50$ psi, measured immediately after it comes out of the shower. I'm considering showers in which you can manually vary the water pressure.

Comment: The pressure immediately after it comes out of the shower is always atmospheric, Unless the flow is supersonic like in a water jet cutter

Comment: I'm considering showers in which you can manually vary the water pressure i.e. it shoots water at a greater force. Apologies if my terminology is incorrect, I'm only a high school student.

Comment: If you are turning the knob and adjusting the Intensity of the flow, It means the thing you are varying is the pressure *inside* the pipe, which varies the velocity of the stream outside the pipe

Comment: Is there a way to determine the pressure based on velocity?

Comment: Not easily, but yes. https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/orifice-flow#:~:text=To%20calculate%20the%20flow%20rate,square%20root%20of%20the%20product.

Comment: Thank you for your help (apologies for the consistent stream of questions). Is there a way now to find the theoretical relationship between velocity and volume collected after, say, 60 seconds.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of Volumetric flow rate? For example Liters per second.  That is what you could directly measure with your bucket and a timer

Comment: I plan to experimentally test this, but I'm wondering if there was any theoretical work on this so I can validate my results.

Comment: You would essentially be measuring not the relationship between pressure and flow for your showerhead, but the flow characteristic curve of your adjustment valve, how the flow varies vs % open. Eg the figure here. It's not a straightforward answer, but you could take measurements and see which curve it is closest to https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/control-valves-flow-characteristics-d_485.html.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I stumbled upon very useful research following your advice.